# What's the meaning of the phrase "set up for" in this context ? (Warning !!! Spoilers for Crime And Punishment by Dostoevsky)

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

This is [an English translation](https://etc.usf.edu/lit2go/182/crime-and-punishment/3400/part-2-chapter-2/) of "Crime And Punishment" by Dostoevsky

It's an exchange between the main protagonist, Raskolnikov and his friend Razumihin, whom he asked whether he can get him lessons(Raskolnikov had a job in which he was teching students). Razumihin says he doesn't have lessons but theres something better, a bookseller.

"He’s doing publishing of a kind, and issuing
natural science manuals and what a circulation they have!
The very titles are worth the money! You always maintained
that I was a fool, but by Jove, my boy, there are greater fools
than I am! Now he **is setting up for** being advanced, not that
he has an inkling of anything, but, of course, I encourage
him."

This is a definition for the phrase "set up for" from TFD:

1. To alter the conditions of someone's or one's own situation so a particular outcome is all but guaranteed.
   *I just think you should manage your expectations about how the party will turn out, or you'll end up setting yourself up for disappointment.*

Does it mean that the bookseller is making some arrangment which will make him an advanced publisher ? And(i'm not shure if i should make a seperate post about it) also, why is he saying
"not that he has an inkling of anything" when he clearly is impressed by the circullation of the magazines?

Comment: Maybe he's arranging (setting up) to publish *advanced* books about natural science, even though he doesn't know anything (has no inkling) about advanced science. As a side suggestion, since this is a translation into English, if you can find another translation, that might help getting to the exact meaning of the original text.

Comment: It means "Теперь в направление тоже полез"

Comment: "he is setting up for being advanced" looks to me like a poor translation. it's a clumsy construction, and the meaning is unclear. Without more information about the context and the translator, it is impossible to say what this might mean.

Comment: This might be better discussed on [russian.se] using the snippet of Russian text, and providing the Garrett translation as context and prior research.